# PHP как удалить письма?

Tags: php, email

Почему письма не удаляются?

```
/* try to connect */ $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password)
or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */ $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */ if($emails) { /*
begin output var */ $output = ''; /* put the newest emails on top */
rsort($emails); /* for every email... */ foreach($emails as
$email_number) { /* get information specific to this email */
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0); $message =
imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

/* output the email header information */ $output.= ''; $output.=
''.$overview[0]->subject.' '; $output.= ''.$overview[0]->from.'';
$output.= 'on '.$overview[0]->date.''; $output.= '';

/* output the email body */ $output.= ''.$message.''; } echo $output;
}  imap_delete ($inbox ,'ALL'); /* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

Еще пробовал `imap_delete ($inbox , 1);` - тоже ничего.

Где ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пропустили вызов `imap_expunge`. Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-expunge.php):

> imap_expunge — Delete all messages marked for deletion